# I get the error 'Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Null' in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, post

I am trying to post a JSON to our api but keep getting this error even if all values are NULL and are allowed to be NULL, here is the code snippet that causes the issue.

```
   final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('http://"api"/api/createPin'),
    body: json.encode({

      'location': Null,
      'description': Null,
      'qrcode': Null,
      'ttl': Null,
      'tier': Null,
      'type': Null,
      'user': Null,
      'images': Null,
      'viewable_users': Null
    }),
    );
```

ive searched forums and also a few videos but none solved my problem and I do not know what im doing wrong.

Comment: use `null` instead of `Null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about changing from `Null` to `null`?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for 'null' and not 'Null'.

Null is a class which cannot be instantiated and null a value.